# why right and left shift keys not working in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Previously I used windows 7, at one time the right and left shift keys were a bit strange, they did their job as functions, but when pressed right SHIFT the cursor would move to the very end of the line, or if there were 2 lines, the cursor would move to the bottom of it.  While the left shift if pressed will go to the very back of the line in the same line.
now i'm using kali linux, i guess the problem is solved, but it's not
what is the keyboard setting?  or something else?

this is the code i did to check:

**`cat -v`**

and the output of the right shift key is

```
^[[B
```

while the output of the left shift key is

```
 ^[[1~
```

if I use an external keyboard, everything seems fine.  But I don't want it on my laptop.

My laptop is TOSHIBA Satellite L645 PSK0GL-09U05L.

sorry if my english is not good, im using google translate btw

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/164143

Comment: @forest not really relevant at all

Comment: The behaviour of these two keys is the same under Windows as under Linux? Then it's something to do with the laptop itself. Please [edit] your question to tell us laptop make/model